# JavaScript code not working with "toLowerCase" on equating it with value received from prompt

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt, lowercase

```
let browser = prompt('Enter browser name','Enter here..');
if (browser.toLowerCase=='edge') {
    alert('You got the Edge!');
} 
else if (browser.toLowerCase=='chrome' || browser.toLowerCase=='firefox' || browser.toLowerCase=='safari' || browser.toLowerCase=='opera') {
    alert('Okay we support these browsers too!')
} 
else {
    alert('We hope this page looks okay!');
}
```

The above code is only executing the "Else" condition (last one).
Removing "toLowerCase" makes it work perfectly, but why don't it works with "toLowerCase"??

Comment: You need to call the method by adding parenthesis: `toLowerCase()`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp, it's toLowerCase()

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `toLowerCase` property, but it does not exists, what you want is to call the `toLowerCase()` function, notice the `()` at the end.

```js
let browser = prompt('Enter browser name','Enter here..');
if (browser.toLowerCase() == 'edge') {
    alert('You got the Edge!');
} 
else if (browser.toLowerCase=='chrome' || browser.toLowerCase=='firefox' || browser.toLowerCase=='safari' || browser.toLowerCase() == 'opera') {
    alert('Okay we support these browsers too!')
} 
else {
    alert('We hope this page looks okay!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`toLowerCase()` is an inherited **method** of strings, not a **property**, so:

```
'foo'.toLowerCase()
```

not

```
'foo'.toLowerCase
```

The latter will simply return a reference to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function `browser.toLowerCase()` ( add the parenthesis `()` )

```js
let browser = prompt('Enter browser name', 'Enter here..');
if (browser.toLowerCase() == 'edge') {
  alert('You got the Edge!');
} else if (browser.toLowerCase() == 'chrome' || browser.toLowerCase() == 'firefox' || browser.toLowerCase() == 'safari' || browser.toLowerCase() == 'opera') {
  alert('Okay we support these browsers too!')
} else {
  alert('We hope this page looks okay!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a String's method not a property so in order to call it you need to use a parenthesis `str.toLowerCase()`.

As for your example you probably could rewrite it like this:

```js
let browser = prompt('Enter browser name','Enter here..');
let browserInLowerCase = browser.toLowerCase();

if (browserInLowerCase === 'edge') {
    alert('You got the Edge!');
} 
else if (browserInLowerCase === 'chrome' || browserInLowerCase === 'firefox' || browserInLowerCase === 'safari' || browserInLowerCase === 'opera') {
    alert('Okay we support these browsers too!')
} 
else {
    alert('We hope this page looks okay!');
};
```

or using the `switch`

```js
let browser = prompt('Enter browser name','Enter here..');
let browserInLowerCase = browser.toLowerCase();

switch(browserInLowerCase) {
  case 'edge':
   alert('You got the Edge!');
  break;
  case 'chrome':
  case 'firefox':
  case 'safari':
  case 'opera':
   alert('Okay we support these browsers too!');
  break;
  default:
   alert('We hope this page looks okay!');
  break;
};
```